# How can AuthLogic be configured to only timeout sessions for certain users (admins)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authlogic

We have a business requirement that some users be automatically logged out of our application after a period of inactivity.  Other users are allowed to stay logged in and should not timeout.   We are using AuthLogic with Rails 3 for session management.

How can I have AuthLogic sessions timeout for some users, but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User must have a last_request_at column, then add this to the UserSessions model.  You can perform whatever check you like in stale? Here the timeout only occurs for administrators.

```
logout_on_timeout true

def stale?
  user.present? && user.admin? && super
end
```